# Android NDK Error using Cygwin: ERROR: GNUMAKE variable is defined to an invalid name

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to build a static library using Android NDK. For this I have installed Cygwin & android-ndk-r7.

To build the library I have already created the required source file and Android.mk file. These files are located under "D:\NDK\test" on my machine.

My NDK Tools are installed under "C:\Android\android-ndk-r7" & Cygwin files are located under "C:\Cygwin\http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirrors.hoobly.com%2f". Hence there are no space in any of the locations.

For building the library, I launch Cygwin and point it to the location where my source files and Android.mk file is located. Then to give the build command I type "/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build". On giving the above command, I get an error message:

> ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
>   or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.

I went through several blogs and followed the solutions on them:

1. Install make under Devel folder in Cygwin installation. This didnt do any change.
2. Create an Environmental Variable GNUMAKE and define it as /usr/bin/make. I also tried defining this variable to different locations:

   > C:\Cygwin\http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirrors.hoobly.com%2f\bin
   >   C:\Android\android-ndk-r7\prebuilt\windows\bin
   >   C:\Android\android-ndk-r7

   But with each I got the same error:

   > ERROR: Your GNUMAKE variable is defined to an invalid name: C:\Android\android-ndk-r7
   >   Please fix it to point to a valid make executable (e.g. /usr/bin/make)

So it looks like I am not pointing the path correctly.
Can someone please tell me which path should GNUMAKE point to.

I also did make -v on my Cygwin prompt and the below message pops up (which makes me believe that everything related to Cygwin installation is fine):

```
$ make -v
```

GNU Make 3.81

Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for Windows32

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting with NDKr7, you don't need Cygwin anymore to build libraries. Here's the simpler way.

1. In command prompt, navigate to your project directory: `cd D:\NDK\test`
2. Make sure your native code and Android.mk are in the jni folder of that directory
3. Call ndk-build: `C:\Android\android-ndk-r7\ndk-build`

This should do it all for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am now able to build the library. I will like to confirm one more thing: In your response you mention native code. I believe that is used for java apps. Right? Right now I am just trying to create an executable so that I can transfer it onto my Galaxy SII and then run it from there to do a File I/O. My Make File right is just compiling the C source code and building it into an executable. Does that sound fine or do I need to have a java code for a complete app?

Comment: When we say Native, we mean non-Java, or rather code that does not run on the virtual machine. What you build are simply libraries, so you still need something to run the program and talk to them, so yes, you either need Java or you can build a fully native Activity. An example of such Activity comes with the NDK.

Comment: I created a NDK executable using $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
To run this executable on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S2) without rooting, I push it to /data folder:
adb push D:\NDK\test /data/local/tmp
To verify, I went to data/local/tmp folder by cd and then I can see the file using ls. Now to run the executable I typed ./test but I get an error:
"permission denied".

I am new to NDK & Android and hence I am not sure if I am missing any step in creating the executable or using it on phone. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

i worked hard on error in gygwin terminal **"gnumake variable is define to invalid name"** and after that i get to the point that we simply remove this error by deleting the GNUMAKE path in environment variable both in system and user variable if u created it....

mycomputer > system properties > advanced system setting > environment variable